# AngularJS $http response misses some content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request, fetch

I'm trying to get the content of a website using Angular's $http service. Apparently the request is successful because console.log(response.data) prints most of the content but omits some of it. This is my code:

```
   $http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http');
   function getAccess(url, token){$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      headers:{"Authorization": 'Bearer '+ token } })

      .then(function(response) {
         console.log(response.data); 
       })
      .catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error);      
       })
    };
```

This is the first part of the omitted html:

```
<div class="container">
::before
<!-- ngView:  -->
   <div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
      <div id="toast-container" ng-class="config.position" class="ng- 
       scope toast-top-right">
         <!-- ngRepeat: toaster in toasters --></div>
      <div ng-controller="ConsultaTransferenciaController" class="ng- 
       scope">
         <h3>Transferencias recibidas - (Mis compras). 
            <a href="" ng-click="infoayuda()"><span style="color:green" 
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"> 
            </span> </a>
         </h3>
```

and goes beyond..
I also tried with Fetch and it gave me the same response. Any idea why this is not included in the response? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you pop open the network tab and look at the response is all of the expected data there?

Comment: Wild guess - Is that HTML pasted from dev tools? The `::before` looks odd. I wonder if that's related to your issue - maybe it's not seen as valid HTML or something?

Comment: Yep, it's pasted from dev tools. I want to retrieve the information inside that container but insted I just retrieve this:                                       
 `<div class="container">
               <div data-ng-view="">
               </div>
             </div>`

Comment: Does the website use a client-side router? `ng-view` looks like a placeholder for content that would be inserted by a router

Comment: @Frank Modica, for what I've read I think it does.

Comment: Then you might be pulling in an HTML placeholder, and the router places content in that later.

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to retrive data from a site with a simple get request. If the site is in plain html that works. But the site you are trying scrape is a single page angular application,  which is a dynamic site with javascript. so this approch wont work. you can use  `panthomjs`
 or `puppeteer` in server side to achieve what you seek.

Comment: can you guys explain the down vote please? then it would be helpful to everyone.